Rest API shows no results
This is the first time I have been trying to integrate with a CiviCRM instance. I have admin rights to the instance, however I am having issues getting the REST API to come back with any results. I am able to get back results using the https://my.sitename.com/civicrm/api4#/explorer// gui, however when I hit it via postman or curl I always get back
{"values":[],"entity":"Contact","action":"get","debug":null,"version":4,"count":0,"countFetched":0}

Example curl
curl --location --request POST 'https://my.sitename.com/civicrm/ajax/api4/Contact/get' \
--header 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
--header 'X-Civi-Auth: Bearer $MYAPIKEY' \
--header 'X-Civi-Key: $SITEKEY' \
--header 'Accept: application/json'


Looks like the connection is successful but the user you are authenticating with does not have permission to view any contacts.

This is where I am a little fuzzy about where using the developer api in the website vs the rest API works. I am signed into the website using the account that the token is assigned to, so I would expect to have the same permissions; that being said it appears that there is some other layer of permissions that is applied to the rest api that I don't understand.

Have you checked these docs? https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v4/rest/

I have been reading this documentation, I think what is maybe hanging me up is line here
For API keys and passwords, the user must have the matching permission (authenticate with api key or authenticate with password).
